# Replace string suffix

Tags: python

In Python we have `.replace()` to replace a substring in a string and now, since Python 3.9, we have `.removesuffix()` to remove specific suffixes from a string.

How can we replace suffix in Python in as simple way as possible, preferably in one short line?

```py
>>> string1 = "hello.world.wo"
>>> string2 = "hello.world"
>>>
>>> string1.removesuffix(".wo")
'hello.world'
>>>
>>> string2.removesuffix(".wo")
'hello.world'
>>>
>>> string1.replace(".wo", ".he")
'hello.herld.he'
>>>
>>> string2.replace(".wo", ".he")
'hello.herld'
>>>
>>> [ SOLUTION HERE with string1 ]
'hello.world.he'
>>>
>>> [ SAME SOLUTION HERE with string2 ]
'hello.world'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `sub` which is a more powerful tool for string operations:

```
import re

string1 = "hello.world.wo"
string2 = "hello.world"

pattern = "\.wo$" # escape dot, $ means end of string

string1 = re.sub(pattern, ".he", string1)
print(string1)
string2 = re.sub(pattern, ".he", string2)
print(string2)
```

Without regex, you can also just check if string ends with suffix and if so, cut it manually:

```
string1 = "hello.world.wo"

suffix = ".wo"

if string1.endswith(suffix):
    string1 = string1[:-len(suffix)] + ".he"

print(string1)
```

The if block can be shortened with if expression:

```
suffix = ".wo"
string1 = string1[:-len(suffix)] + ".he" if string1.endswith(suffix) else string1
```

Answer (score 0):

A [regex replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regex anchored to the string end would do the job:

```
import re

result = re.sub(r'\.wo$', '.he', original)
```

Note that `$` matches both the end of the string, or right before a trailing newline, so this would turn `'x.wo\n'` into `'x.he\n'`. If you want to avoid that, you can use a negative lookahead to assert there's no newline after the `$`:

```
result = re.sub(r'\.wo$(?!\n)', '.he', original)
```

However, this gets kind of messy, and it can be very slow for large strings. Compare the performance of a regex-based approach to replacing a 1-character suffix of a 100000-character string:

```
In [21]: x = 'a'*100000

In [22]: %timeit re.sub(r'a$(?!\n)', 'b', x)  # suffix present
1.06 ms ± 478 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit re.sub(r'c$(?!\n)', 'b', x)  # suffix absent
72.8 µs ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

to the over 300x speedup of just using simple string methods:

```
In [24]: %%timeit
    ...: if x.endswith('a'):  # suffix present
    ...:     y = x.removesuffix('a') + 'b'
    ...: else:
    ...:     y = x
    ...: 
2.91 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [25]: %%timeit
    ...: if x.endswith('c'):  # suffix absent
    ...:     y = x.removesuffix('c') + 'b'
    ...: else:
    ...:     y = x
    ...: 
155 ns ± 2.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```